# Change title of blogger

Tags: html, blogger

Hii i would like to change the blogger title at this time my blog title is **"My Super Xbox Games"** (without quote) and when i make a new post the title is attached my my post title, here is code to show only post title. (adding it to html template)

Find

```
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
```

And replace it with:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
<title><data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/></title>
</b:if>
```

Ok here is structure of blogger url,

Blogger pages include /p in url...
Blogger posts include year and month like 2013/11 in url...
Blogger label include label word in url...
Blogger archives include archives word in url ...

Now if you want to make hyperlink in a way that every label, post and pages section should change the anchor text or website link then you use if statement like this.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'><a href='http://mywebsite.com/' target='_blank'>my keyword</a>
</b:if> <b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'><a href='http://mywebsite.com/' target='_blank'>another keyword</a></b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'><a href='http://mywebsite.com/' target='_blank'>other keyword</a></b:if><b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'><a href='http://mywebsite.com/' target='_blank'>one another keyword</a></b:if>
<b:else/><a href='http://mywebsite.com/' target='_blank'>new keyword</a></b:if>
```

Now how do i use this statement in blog title that if my main index page open it display the blog title "My Super Xbox Games" (without quote) and if any other page is open it dispaly the title **"Xbox Games"** (without quote) just remove the my super word, along with my post title. you can also get some info about it [here](http://www.bloggersentral.com/2009/06/showing-title-only-in-archive-label-and.html) if you want

*Remember i don't want to remove the title from just change want to make a little change.*

Comment: Why is this tagged java and php?

Comment: May be java and php developer have some knowledge about it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add these condition manually in  tag, your issue will be resolve.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<title>My Super Xbox Games</title>
<b:else/>
<title>Xbox Games</title>
</b:if>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The [article](http://www.bloggersentral.com/2009/06/showing-title-only-in-archive-label-and.html) you shared is a tutorial about something else.It shows how to show only the title and not summary.

Your question is how to show some title on 1 page and a variant of it on a different the page.

To the best of my knowledge,the same is not supported by Blogger API.